# Increase openfire memory to larger values

Tags: performance, memory, java, xmpp, openfire

We use OpenFire for XMPP messages. We have some memory issues(OutOfMemoryError), and therefor we would like to increase memory. I know how to increase memory using VM options and we were able to increase memory to 1.5Gb.

We use a 32bit VM, since it appears 64bit VM's are not supported on OpenFire

My question: Is there anyone out there that was able to increase OpenFire memory to larger then 1.5GB values? if so, please learn me how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [you're out of luck](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit).

> Why can't I get a larger heap with the 32-bit JVM?
>
> The maximum theoretical heap limit for the 32-bit JVM is 4G. Due to
>   various additional constraints such as available swap, kernel address
>   space usage, memory fragmentation, and VM overhead, in practice the
>   limit can be much lower. On most modern 32-bit Windows systems the
>   maximum heap size will range from 1.4G to 1.6G. On 32-bit Solaris
>   kernels the address space is limited to 2G. On 64-bit operating
>   systems running the 32-bit VM, the max heap size can be higher,
>   approaching 4G on many Solaris systems.